# How can I replace elements of a matrix based on another matrix of indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have two matrices like this,

```
I1 = [[3, 1], [4, 3], [2, 3]]
I2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now I want to change the values of `I2` from 0 to 1, in the indexes represented by items from `I1`.

For example:

```
I1[0] = [3, 1]
I2[3][1] = 1
```

And the same for all other elements of `I1`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: You need numpy arrays for this really, not python _lists_

Comment: while this one is much simpler with numpy, it easily can be done with lists

Comment: @Marcin indeed, I went back and edited after realising my mistake :)

Comment: Assigning to a list element is covered in any tutorial on Python lists.  How are you stuck?  Again, post your problem code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
I1 = [[3, 1], [4, 3], [2, 3]]
I2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

for i, j in I1:
  I2[i][j] = 1
```

Now I2 will be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```